# Firebase Rule never returning a request.response

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

When I run a Firebase/Firestore query in app or simulator with a Security Rule using *request.response* it consistently fails the check. The simulator throws an "Error: simulator.rules line [XX], column [XX]. **Property resource is undefined on object.**"

That would imply the document I'm querying isn't real. It exists in my db, and just in case the simulator doesn't check real documents, I'm making sure to do a sim "create" call for the document immediately before running the get. No actual document ID that I insert seems to be found in this collection or any other for that matter. Clearly overlooking something vital and probably absurdly basic:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /responses/{id} {
        allow read: 
             if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.userID;        
  }
}
```

FYI The query is authenticated, and I'm hitting the path "responses/documentName" which does in fact exist with a "userID" property.  Rules that don't use the request.response are working fine.

This is clearly a super boilerplate rule/query. What am I overlooking?

Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, `request.resource` does not exist. It only exists on writes

Try this instead:

```
if request.auth.uid == resource.data.userID;
```